# Axios request failing for localhost, but working when I specify its IP

Tags: typescript, axios, debian

I recently got an AWS Lightsail instance for my Node projects, both my database and Node projects are running on this server.

However, I have a built-in API in NextJS which I call in my client pages. The GET request to `localhost` works just fine, but whenever I post to `localhost` I get a `Network Error`.

When I change the IP to the static IP from the server, it works just fine. I need to use `localhost` though so I can develop (and run) the project on other machines. Here is my code:

```js
    axios
      .post<post>("http://localhost:3000/api/posts", post, {
        headers,
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(post => {
        window.location.reload();
      })
      .catch(async error => {
        console.error("AXIOS ERROR:");
        console.error(await error);
      })
```

As I said, when I change `localhost` to the IP the server is running on, it works just fine. How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Most probably CORS issue. What is your localhost server running on? express.js?

Comment: Are you sure your backend is on 3000 port and not on something like 8000?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to remove the IP alltogether:

```
    axios
      .post<post>("http://localhost:3000/api/posts", post, {
        headers,
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(post => {
        window.location.reload();
      })
      .catch(async error => {
        console.error("AXIOS ERROR:");
        console.error(await error);
      })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).